# Creating a collection of beans in Spring using @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration, collections, annotations

How can I create a collection of beans that will be properly managed by Spring using a class with a @Configuration annotation.

I would like to do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public Config {
    @Autowired
    private SomeConfiguration config;

    @Bean
    public List<MyBean> myBeans() {
        List<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
        for (Device device : config.getDevices()) {
            beans.add(new MyBean(device));
        }
        return beans;
    }
}
```

But the MyBean instances aren't post processed. So their @Autowired methods are not called, the beans are not registered as mbeans and etc. The list is however accessible so that I can autowire a List of MyBean objects.

I cannot use something like:

```
@Configuration
public Config {
    @Autowired
    private SomeConfiguration config;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean1() { ... }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean2() { ... }
}
```

Since the number of MyBean instances are not known before runtime. The reason I want to do this is because we are controlling a physical machine that have a variable amount of components. And I want to have one bean per component.

I'm currently achieving our goal by using a BeanFactoryPostProcessor like this:

```
@Component
public class MyBeansFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private SomeConfiguration config;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeanException {
        for (Device device : config.getDevices()) {
            createAndRegister(BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory, device);
        }
    }

    private void createAndRegister(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, Device device) {
        register.registerBeanDefinition("device" + device.getId(), BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(MyBean.class).addConstructorArgValue(device).getBeanDefinition());
    }
}
```

But this just feels like a really ugly hack.

Comment: Still no acceptable and good answer on this not so uncommon use case? That's crazy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory` which supports `SmartLifecycle` so if you register the bean before your app is fully initialized it will call `start()` for you and other post processing steps.

However - if you call `beanFactory.registerSingleton` after spring has initialized you will manually need to call `start()` - on the bright side though you bean is still fully wired into the lifecycle management and spring will call `stop()` for you when the application context is shutdown.

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@Bean
public List<MyBean> myBeansList() {

    List<MyBean> mylist; // Construct your list dynamically

    while(myCondition) {
        MyBean bean;
        // Manually register each instance with Spring
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("unique-name-for-this-bean",bean);
    }

    // Return your list as a bean so you can still autowire the list of beans
    // but each bean has already been manually added to the context
    return mylist;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me where you would call the start() from? 
I have asked this is a follow up question to your answer as I can’t quite get it to work
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77547518/6395235

Answer (score 4):

I believe that another option in this case is to use `@PostConstruct` in the following manner:

```
@Configuration
public Config {

    @Autowired
    private SomeConfiguration config;

    List<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<MyBean>();

    @Bean
    public List<MyBean> myBeans() {     
    
        return beans;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for (Device device : config.getDevices()) {
            beans.add(new MyBean(device));
        }   
    }
}
```

The `@PostConstruct` annotation is useful for initializing properties. It guarantees that the annotated method will only be called once when the bean is created.

Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 3):

In order to inject your `MyBean` list try `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`. for e.g.

```
@Resource
public List<MyBean> myBeans
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible using `@Configuration` to define more than one bean per method (AFAIK). So you will have to contnue using a BFPP or use `ApplicationContect.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowire(object);`

Comment: Thanks this will ensure that all @Autowired methods are called. But  it doesn't register the beans with JMX and apply other post processing. I've also tried
 `ApplicationContect.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);`
 `ApplicationContect.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);`
But since there are no bean definitions they will not perform full post processing.

Comment: @pcm that makes sense, then I guess you are already doing it the best possible way

Answer (score 0):

`MyBeans` are not post processed as they are created with `new` and not initialised by the Spring container.

You need to use prototype beans, have an instance of a new bean per request made by a component.

You will need to tag your `MyBean(Device device)` bean declaration like

`@Bean @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`

Then call that instead of using `new` where you populate `beans`.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up extending the ArrayList.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Autowired
    private SomeConfiguration config;

    @Bean
    public List<MyBean> myBeans() {
        List<MyBean> beans = new MyBeanList();
        for (final Device device : config.getDevices()) {
            beans.add(new MyBean(device));
        }
        return beans;
    }

    private static class MyBeanList extends ArrayList<MyBean> {
        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            this.forEach(bean -> bean.init());
        }

        @PreDestroy
        public void close() {
            this.forEach(bean -> bean.close());
        }
    }
}
```

This is, of course, hacky but feels a less uglier than the questioners approach.