# How to dynamically create N beans based on configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create N number of beans of type `DynamicStringMaker` in my code based on the configuration values provided as an array. This is intended to be packaged up and called by other applications, gated by a `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation.

I have the issue that following [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52106568/6395235) I either need to find a way to always create the `myBeansList` bean, even if it is not used or I would have to auto wire it in somewhere and never use it.

I have tried to use the `@PostConstruct` annotation instead, but then the named beans are not created so I get a null pointer exception when trying to use it, or the app doesn't start (using required = true/false)

[This is a simple example of a more complex codebase that I have at work so it is a little noddy. Here it is not working as the bean method is never called](https://github.com/SSmale/SpringBoot/commit/9405a56dc012598f8a8ca9133b7fb945aac57e2d)

[It working because I AutoWire in the array](https://github.com/SSmale/SpringBoot/commit/22c1e616599e77f2495a24b9b73915014d58575b)

```
// BeanMaking Class
package uk.co.iamsimonsmale.facades.DynmicString.autoconfigure;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import uk.co.iamsimonsmale.facades.DynmicString.DynamicStringMaker;
import uk.co.iamsimonsmale.facades.DynmicString.ConfigurationProperties.Multi;
import uk.co.iamsimonsmale.facades.DynmicString.ConfigurationProperties.Single;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class multiDynamicStrings {

  @Autowired
  private Multi multiConfig;

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  @Bean
  public Map<String, DynamicStringMaker> makeMakers() {
    Map<String, DynamicStringMaker> beanList = new HashMap<>();

    log.info(multiConfig.lastName());

    for (Single config : multiConfig.configs()) {
      DynamicStringMaker newBean = new DynamicStringMaker(multiConfig.lastName(), config.firstName());
      beanFactory.registerSingleton(config.beanName(), newBean);
    }

    return beanList;

  }

}
```

```
# BeanConfig
uk.co.iamsimonsmale.dynamic-strings:
  lastName: Smale
  configs:
    - beanName: simonBean
      firstName: Simon
    - beanName: griffinBean
      firstName: Griffin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beans' definitions should be registered earlier in the lifecycle of the Spring application context, before the bean instantiation phase. To do so, you can implement [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) as follows:

```java
public class DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar
    implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  public static final String PROPERTIES_PREFIX = "uk.co.iamsimonsmale.dynamic-strings";
  private final Multi multi;

  public DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar(Environment environment) {
    multi =
        Binder.get(environment)
            .bind(PROPERTIES_PREFIX, Bindable.of(Multi.class))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry)
      throws BeansException {
    multi.configs().forEach(config -> registerBeanDefinition(registry, config));
  }

  private void registerBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, Single config) {
    GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setBeanClass(DynamicStringMaker.class);
    beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(
        () -> new DynamicStringMaker(multi.lastName(), config.firstName()));
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(config.beanName(), beanDefinition);
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
      throws BeansException {}
}
```

Since properties are needed before beans are instantiated, to register `DynamicStringMaker` beans' definitions, `@ConfigurationProperties` are unsuitable for this case. Instead, [Binder API](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#configuration-property-binding) is used to bind them programmatically.

Because `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` objects, in general, must be instantiated very early in the lifecycle, `@Bean` methods should be marked as static in `@Configuration` classes to avoid lifecycle issues, according to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

```java
@Configuration
public class DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrarConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public static DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar beanDefinitionRegistrar(Environment environment) {
    return new DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar(environment);
  }
}
```

To use those beans, you can either inject one by a bean name or all of them as a collection.

For reference: [Dynamically register Spring Beans based on properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046618/10231374)

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. 

To pick up one of my points about conditional on property, that can be added to the bean def too https://github.com/SSmale/SpringBoot/commit/03006d35741db6b1839c13f17198dff644c52f18

Comment: @Tony, When I got to the more complex codebase I ran into other troubles. I have posted a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563863/how-to-instantiate-n-beans-that-require-a-3rd-party-bean-to-create-a-wrapper-a)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom implementation of a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. Create it and register it as a normal bean.

Basically instead of registering many beans at runtime like your `@Configuration` tries to do, it would register many **bean definitions** earlier in the lifecycle of the application context, based on the `Environment`'s properties.

You can use the `registry.registerBeanDefinition(<dynamicBeanName>, BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(DynamicStringMaker.class)  .addConstructorArgValue(firstname).addConstructorArgValue(lastname).getBeanDefinition())`. It's like creating `@Bean` methods manually. The definitions will be processed and the beans created. You can then inject them however you want.

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure where or how that would work. Any chance you would be able to add it to the repo code or put the class here?