# How to instantiate N beans that require a 3rd party bean, to create a wrapper, and then instantiate N more beans using the wrapper as a named Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I tried to implement [the answer from another question I had asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77547518/how-to-dynamically-create-n-beans-based-on-configuration/77547803) in my main codebase and I had oversimplified the problem.

In my codebase I am dependant on an AutoConfigured bean from a 3rd party package (A custom HTTP Client) and I have to create N beans based on the number of items in the yaml config array to create a wrapper of the 3rd party client.

I then need to create another N beans of a different type that take one of the above named beans as input and create an other named bean. This is the one used in my application.

```
# BeanConfig
uk.co.iamsimonsmale.dynamic-strings:
  url: http:localhost:8000/api
  configs:
    - beanName: simonBean
      userName: Simon
      password: ABC
    - beanName: griffinBean
      userName: Griffin
      password: XYZ
```

So for the above config I would use `CustomHttpClient` to create 2 beans `simonBeanHttp` and `griffinBeanHttp` and then create 2 more beans `simonBeanClient` and `griffinBeanClient` with the `*Client` bean depending on its respectively named `*Http` bean.

Testing the code from the other question, I was not sure how to create them when they required the `CustomHtppClient` as it was not created yet, and then how to either use 1 class and loop to create both the `*Client` bean and `*Http` bean (how do I get access to the bean rather than its definition) or pass in the bean via its name dynamically via the `DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar`.

I did also try to create another map of the `*Client` beans (as I don't need these outside of this setup process) and pass that map into the `*Http` registrar, but that was also missing the `CustomHttpClient`

Comment: Why not give the `DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar` from the accepted answer in your linked question the `CustomHttpClient` for spring boot to autowire it so you can use it when the string makers are created?

Comment: @daniu, that was my first idea, but the CustomHttpClient is not yet a bean so can’t be used. I get an exception to create a bean with name ‘CustomHttpClient’

Comment: What do you mean "is not yet a bean", you say it's autoconfigured, that means it's created. What happens when you add a constructor parameter of type `CustomHttpClient` to `DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar`?

Comment: I think the beans are not yet instantiated, "before beans are instantiated" - from the other answer, I get an application failed to start as the 'CustomHttpClient' bean is not there, similar to this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining bean dependencies in `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` can be tricky sometimes, especially considering that beans are not instantiated yet, they can't be passed as a parameter to a constructor in `setInstanceSupplier`.

Spring can handle the injection for you if the setter injection is used instead of the constructor injection. All you need to do is define a setter for the dependency, mark it as `@Autowired`, and remove the property from the constructor. This solution is applicable to the first case, where `CustomHttpClient` should be injected into `Http` beans.

However, for the second case, where `Http` beans' names are defined at runtime, setter injection is not applicable, because Spring can't determine which bean to inject to `Client` beans. Instead, the bean name can be defined in `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` while registering `Client` beans.

Let's assume, the `Http` and `Client` classes look like this:

```java
public final class Http {
  private CustomHttpClient customHttpClient;
  private final String userName;
  private final String password;
  private final String url;

  public Http(String url, String userName, String password) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.url = url;
  }

  @Autowired
  public void setCustomHttpClient(CustomHttpClient customHttpClient) {
    this.customHttpClient = customHttpClient;
  }

  // ...
}
```

```java
public class Client {
  private Http http;

  public void setHttp(Http http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Below is the modified `DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar` from [the referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547803/10231374).

```java
public class DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar
    implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  public static final String PROPERTIES_PREFIX = "uk.co.iamsimonsmale.dynamic-strings";
  private final Multi multi;

  public DynamicStringMakerBeanDefinitionRegistrar(Environment environment) {
    multi =
        Binder.get(environment)
            .bind(PROPERTIES_PREFIX, Bindable.of(Multi.class))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry)
      throws BeansException {
    multi.configs().forEach(config -> registerBeanDefinitions(registry, config));
  }

  private void registerBeanDefinitions(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, Single config) {
    registerHttpBeanDefinition(registry, config);
    registerClientBeanDefinition(registry, config);
  }

  private void registerHttpBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, Single config) {
    GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setBeanClass(Http.class);
    beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(
        () -> new Http(multi.url(), config.userName(), config.password()));
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(config.beanName().concat("Http"), beanDefinition);
  }

  private void registerClientBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, Single config) {
    BeanDefinitionBuilder beanDefinitionBuilder =
        BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Client.class)
            // This method can be used to inject dependency to constructor argument
            //.addConstructorArgReference(config.beanName().concat("Http")) 
            .addPropertyReference("http", config.beanName().concat("Http"));
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(
        config.beanName().concat("Client"), beanDefinitionBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
      throws BeansException {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this again today! Can you point me at any resources for further reading into this kind of bean creation? It seems pretty advanced knowledge and I would like to better understand the code, to prevent further questions and allow me to help answer others

Comment: I'd recommend official javadocs: [BeanDefinitionBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.html) and [GenericBeanDefinition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/GenericBeanDefinition.html).  Additionally, you might find valuable insights from the community here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, This worked, but I needed to use @Lazy on the client beans when AutoWired (config.beanName().concat("Client"))

Comment: Slight follow up for this, how do I ensure the password has been unencrypted by the JASPYT lib (https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/issues/310)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help you with that.